# Function to style TextField borders in swift not working

Tags: ios, swift

so I am new to Swift and mobile development, I want to make function that Change TextField style so i don't have to write long code for each TextField i have.

This is what I am trying to do :

```
func borderstyle(TextField : UITextField){

    self.TextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 46/225, green: 204/225, blue: 113/225, alpha: 1).CGColor;
    self.TextField.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(Float(1.0));
    self.TextField.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(Float(0.0));

}
```

I think you can get what i am trying to make form the code , the problem is that TextField in the func is read as @IBOutlet while its not.

I want to style any TextField I have with something like this :

```
borderstyle(UserNameTextField) // UserNameTextField is @IBOutlet
```

I know that I am doing some kind of mistake there but I want to know whats the best way to solve that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you pass a textField to the function and then you use self.textField inside of it?

Use:

```
TextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 46/225, green: 204/225, blue: 113/225, alpha: 1).CGColor;
TextField.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(Float(1.0));
TextField.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(Float(0.0));
```

Comment: yes i know this is working but using borderstyle("UserNameTextField") would be much easer spicily if i add more style

Comment: No, I mean, you have to remove self.   It refer to a class property, not the one you're passing to the function...

Comment: using `self.TextField` points to a stored property with that name. Now if you just remove the self and pass a `UITextField` to the method as you have shown, it will set the desired properties on the passed textField

Answer (score 1):

Remove the self pointer from the code.

```
func borderstyle(textField : UITextField){

textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 46/225, green: 204/225, blue: 113/225, alpha: 1).CGColor;
textField.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(Float(1.0));
textField.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(Float(0.0));
```

}

NB: As a good naming concept follow camelCase as shown

Comment: yep :) .. thanks :) , I tried to remove them before and it didn't work coz i used to have String instate of UITextField .. thanks